# Average of Verts position using python

Tags: python

iam really new to python, so I dont even know where to start solving my problem...
I am trying to fit a plane trough a selection of vertices,
as a first step I would like to "merge" or average the position of a selection of vertices into a point or set of XYZ coordinates.
then I would like to extract (somehow) the first and last vert of my selection,
and use the 2 points with the earlier created averaged third point, to create a plane from 3 points... if this is possible using blender and python.
what would be a good way to solve this?

Comment: Well iterate through the verts  (assign the first to a variable) and continuously update the average until you have the last vert, which you have to put in a variale as well. Make a new vert at the average position. Make a plane from the 3 verts

Comment: It is possible using blender and python.  To clarify, using the default cube with all verts selected as a test case. It has centre of geometry at (0, 0, 0) this is also the _average_ of all vert coordinates.  You wish to make a plane using the origin and the first and last selected corner verts? Should the plane be in  the same mesh or  a different object.  Simply making a triangular face with 3 verts will produce a "plane".    A plane can be defined via a location and a normal. The cross product of any two non parallel vectors on plane is the normal.

Comment: Hi, as a total beginner in python, I was hoping that someone could give me a few hints or a feww lines as starting point.